# "При этом" бывает вводным словом или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Мэр подписал все бумаги на строительство гипермаркета в центре города, получив при этом неплохой "откат".

Ведь здесь можно "при этом" выбросить из контекста и смысл не изменится. Тогда получается, что оно вводное и его нужно выделить запятыми? Или нет?  Но нигде в правилах я так и не нашел, что "при этом" может быть вводным словом.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "при этом" союз и наречие. Запятыми выделяется только союз. В вашем случае наречие и не требует запятых.

[**См.Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010.**](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=724.hXkr3CKxXfk5THkRNiJPC_svo0ynPiGouiucZ3C-S_qhc6S4WfPHvn-XsFqgkoPrf1z-I7sFREP66VX2le3s0dBEcnjvq_PM9S5aDl7G_LGB6ZmTLMs6hPFsBgkYtj5C.c1097858cc3cadfe2c08b21e61d33d4845cc5eec&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9aJ2gf1Q1OEQHP1rbfzHEMvZEAs4QuMnSA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxc2dUQ3JNcXNpSTJUZkVrS0g3VmYyZzg5X1laQ0ZtT2lJSHRDbUZyVS1KeFVSMnBQck1qLU5MQ0ZKRmVwcVhGb0NDNUVUVUVxRmM0SHRjUUZzOFVQUTRmMm5URXczdnZ6WnpNbWxWY2RlZ05XV1BfcDdJUkFIQUttd0Yxdm9NakdacmJ6dDlITFNyUzQ4RlRhTVBaUEZuSDNvZ1BBeTVnbFE&b64e=2&sign=08376b361b64d03eb3144b1464af1051&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQYtNprRPFzufqudLJZKAOLwoDTdQIxazSeWiChev90bYFecXuYsoEILGqe2iQuYNBAIfCYs4mwFYsgQjaP6zpYkvQV9_7YxDbaLlFN7B6xOgvF7VS7Go7_l-YEX1UzB8DTz8qHHyc4TAYpfNnUdtO-8JEVStd6LICPVOiZ6V_ahPYiaVbBgnLTwwvcHDFgzsj1RNZE0mRh31&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHtkusEOiLu3mdB1NJZzO2O5XHoXPuLE8BMyc83GmEbmMLBiV02BVCqSSiUTFvh5-qHumCKTmySZbpgpjb3hgnIRY14H0teI9yKwRafCLrvrXv-Ar5Vv49T4FRou7xaglEJiWVYDhjq4KL2KyELQsBW-4v7Vqg4Ow5gfsvDwbd_xh5UV9XjkTa3NZ1YYgzIeNAjmbkF1CMVYG7aF0nN6GNft4kPY8jgRXL4WExK5oyGUVNElq2ZL_RbU-FZ0h_uE_cbqfFNSmVAKyy45TTLF-Um5lUKrT66CZmqQpYrXIYiPjDwEN1x6Fx8w&l10n=ru&cts=1434721014859&mc=3.4613201402110083)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но если здесь "при этом"  все же выделить запятыми, хотя-бы факультативно, это будет считаться ошибкой?

Comment: Да. Запятые здесь не требуются.

Answer (score 1):

Из возможности изъять слово не следует, что оно вводное: можно на это же место поставить столь же необязательное "за услуги" - тоже без запятых. Непросто сделать "при этом" вводными словами в каком-либо предложении. Запятую после него легализовать можно, видимо, только от другого оборота. Разве что с двоеточием можно что-то сочинить:

При этом: а) оказалось занятым место предполагаемой постройки храма, б) пришлось упразднить трамвайный маршрут.

Но и здесь двоеточие обусловлено не вводностью, а последующим перечислением.

Answer (score 1):

Это же явно обстоятельство, и уже поэтому не может быть вводным словом.